# makes you wish he *would* have written

Tags: modal-verbs, modality

> This makes you wish the author **would** have written several advanced
>   sequels to this amazing book.

I don't like **would** in the sentence. Because you usually say "I *wish he had* written..." So for me the sentence should be "..makes you *wish he had* written..."

Can you explain this usage?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with one of the meanings of the verb *will*? Here in its past form – *would*.

Comment: I would much prefer "I wish he had written" as well. The other sounds a bit dodgy to me, but I'm not certain enough to say that it's definitely wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This makes you **wish** the author **would have written** several advanced sequels to this amazing book.

You are right that *"**I wish he had written** ..."* is preferred.

However, in informal speech, *"**I wish he'd have written** ..."* and its variants, *"**I wish he had have written** ..."* and *"**I wish he would have written** ..."*, though frequently considered incorrect, happen quite often in educated people's speech (according to entry 262.2 in PEU, see below).

I found this explanation in *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan,

> **630 wish**
>   **4 *wish* + *that*-clause: tenses**
>   In a *that*-clause after *wish*, we generally use the same tenses as we would use, [...]. Past tenses are used with a present or future meaning.
>   [...]
>   Past perfect tenses are used for wishes about the past.
>       *I wish you **hadn't said** that.* (= It would be nice if you hadn't said that.)
>       *Now she wishes she **had gone** to university.*
>   In informal speech, sentences like *I wish you'd have seen it* sometimes occur. For similar structures with **if**, see 262.

Here are the relevant sections under entry 262 (for the usage of *I wish you'd have ...*).

> **262 if (7): other structures found in spoken English**
>   **2 *'d have ... 'd have***
>   In informal spoken English, *if*-clauses referring to the past are sometimes constructed with *'d have*. This is frequently considered incorrect, but happens quite often in educated people's speech. It is not normally written.
>       ***If I'd have*** known, I'd have told you.
>       *It would have been funny if **she'd have** recognised him.*
>   
>   **3 *had've and would've***
>   Instead of the contracted *'d* in these structures, full forms are sometimes used for emphasis or in negatives. Both *had* and *would occur*. The following are genuine examples taken from conversation.
>       *I didn't know. But **if** I **had've known** ...*
>       *We would never have met **if** he **hadn't have** crashed into my car.*
>       ***If*** I **would've** had a gun, somebody might have got hurt.
>       ***If*** you **wouldn't have** phoned her we'd never have found out what was happening.

Comment: In my copy of Swan's book, this is called **parallel structures: 'd have ... 'd have** (section 261, point 9, page 251). Personally, I don't understand how a conditional tense can convey the meaning of an action that hasn't happened.

Comment: @Nico People often (subconsciously or not) speak as though the past can change (or have been different). It's a hypothetical in the same way as above, it just uses a time in the past as its point of departure from reality.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung I understand that the past tense can be used to talk about hypothetical actions. What I don't understand is the use of the conditional tense for anything other than conditional phrases (if..., then...).

Comment: @Nico I lack the technical understanding to describe the distinctions at play. Please help yourself to any words of mine. _Mis palabras son tus palabras._

Comment: I've quickly looked up the   
[BYU-BNC](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/) and it shows these parallel structures being uses in a wide range of contexts: academic, non-academic, politics...

Comment: It is interesting, though, that the [BYU-BNC](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/) only contains 3 occurrances of `wish + would have + past-participle`, all of them in conversation.

Answer (score 3):

[Wish + would](http://www.eslbase.com/grammar/wish) can be used.

Here is the pattern: *wish* + *would* + bare infinitive to express impatience, annoyance or dissatisfaction with a present action.

- I wish you would stop smoking.  ... You are smoking at the moment and it is annoying me.
- I wish it would stop raining. ... I'm impatient because it is raining and I want to go outside.
- I wish she'd be quiet. ... I am annoyed because she is speaking.

However, in our example: ‘This makes you wish the author would have written several advanced sequels to this amazing book.’, the usage of wish + would is not correct as it refers to a past event.
The correct construction should be: ‘I wish he had written’.

Comment: As described in your answer, `wish+would` expresses dissatisfaction with a **present action**. In OP's case, he's dissatisfied with a **past event**, and hence this construct is not correct.

Comment: To give you a lead, here's a [link](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/wishes-and-hypotheses) to a piece of grammar that briefly tells you that `wish` is followed by a verb in past tense (`would` being the corresponding past-tense form of `will`). I'm sure you can find a better reference and correct your answer.