# 3rd conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions

Watching a series on the web and using subtitles I came across this conditional sentence:

> "I wouldn't have been in jeopardy if you hadn't have planted that sword".

I am a bit puzzled by the use/addition of "have" in order to form the past perfect in the if clause. I have checked a number of English grammars and I cannot find an example of past perfect of this type.

Comment: I answered something similar once. Check out this answer: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/18065/3281. Look for "if he hadn't have crashed into my car".

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of formal English, you are quite correct. It's a mistake.<sup>†</sup>

But there is another point of view. This is a written representation of colloquial English, where something extraordinarily interesting has been going on for the past century, perhaps longer. (I haven't made a study of the scholarly literature on the subject, where you will find better descriptions and more detailed history; this is just my own observation.)

Use of the historic modal verbs is contracting—*tharf* disappeared six centuries ago, *mote* is now restricted to its past form *must*, *shall* scrabbles out a meagre living in the law, *could/might/should/would* are collapsing in sense and are in many respects distinct lexemes from *can/may/shall/will*. New forms are arising to replace them: *be ableda* for *can*, *be gonna* for *will*, *hafta/hasta/hadta* for *must*.

And as the utility of the historic modals declines, English is reinventing an entire set of inflections that was given up as lost a century ago—the subjunctive. The vernacular seems to be marrying the established contractions *’'ve→’a* (representing *have*) and *n’t→’n* (representing *not*) and attaching these to past-form auxiliaries (or to their contractions to *’d*) as subjunctive affixes *’a* (positive) and *’na* (negative).

> I wouldna been in jeopardy if you hadna planted that sword.

(With *might* this is accompanied by assimilation of the /t/ to /d/, *mighda*/*mighdna*, and with *must* the /t/ is elided in the negative, *musna*.)

This only becomes problematic when you attempt to translate this into formal English. Users naturally expand the contractions they perceive into acceptable formal *forms*, as if the affixes represented the contractions from which they derive:

> I wouldn’t have been ... if you hadn’t have.

But they don’t represent those contractions any more. They have become grammaticalized and have evolved into an independent life-form.

---

<sup>†</sup>This should not be (mis)understood as what ideologues are fond of calling ‘prescriptivist’ arbitrariness. Formal English is a distinct dialect, which like all dialects has its own rules, and this construction violates those rules.